# Azure SQL DB query convert to JSON with Flask API

Tags: python, json, api, azure-sql-database

I am trying to query a SQL Server database hosted on Azure through a flask API and convert the results to JSON, what I am trying is below. And this is working, however the results are coming through with escape characters. There don't appear to be any special characters obvious in the data. If I use the API and exec a stored procedure with a parameter the json will come through in the format that I want it. Any suggestions on how to alter this so that I get standard json format?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('customer')

conn = pyodbc.connect(serverconnectionstring)

class Customer(Resource):
    def get(self):     
        cursor = conn.cursor()    
        query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[testforjson]"
        result = cursor.execute(query)
        items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in cursor.description], row)) for row in result]
        jsonitems = json.dumps(items)
        return jsonitems

api.add_resource(Customer, '/customer')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


example output: 
"[{\"field1\": \"B2653\", \"field2\": \"ERLOP\"}, {\"field1\": \"C2653\", \"field2\": \"ERLOP\"}]


desired output:
[
  {
    "field1": "B2653",
    "field2": "ERLOP"
  },
  {
    "field1": "C2653",
    "field2": "ERLOP"
  }
]
```

Comment: did you try returning `items` directly from that `get` method?

Comment: I had not tried that, looks like it worked! Thank you!

Comment: (quick explanation: if you return an object, flask will attempt to return a json representation and set the json content type. If you return a string, flask doesn't know your intention, and sends a string content type. It's then up to your client to figure out what the intention was. In most cases a string content type means the result is presented to you as a string. But you can also ignore the content type and parse that string as json)

Comment: Thank you for adding that, it helps a lot.

Comment: Hi @khennenf , is the error solved now?

Comment: Yes, returning items directly from the get method did exactly what I needed.

Comment: @khennenf Glad to hear that. Very thanks for njzk2! I help him post it as answer to end this question.  hope you can think about accept it as answer. This can be very beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks for @njzk2's help and detailed explanation. I help post it as answer to end this question:

Please try returning items directly from that get method:

- quick explanation: if you return an object, flask will attempt to
  return a json representation and set the json content type. If you
  return a string, flask doesn't know your intention, and sends a
  string content type. It's then up to your client to figure out what
  the intention was. In most cases a string content type means the
  result is presented to you as a string. But you can also ignore the
  content type and parse that string as json

Glad to hear it worked for you. Thanks @njzk3 again. This can be beneficial to other community members.